# What 'this' means in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I just put a 'this' at the beginning of JavaScript, it's not in any functions. Does 'this' have the same meaning with 'document'? or it means window?

Example:

```
$(this).ajaxComplete(handler);
```

In this case, do I attache the handler to the window or the document or something else?

Comment: `window`, probably, but I can't tell without further context.

Comment: `console.log(this);`

Comment: It mainly means that you are assigning the current object to a variable, apart from that this is always the global object - the window.

Comment: @jp310 - "this" in a function constructor is not the same as the window object. It depends on context and has scope.

Comment: I recommend to read the MDN documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: It's worth reading some long articles and tutorials on the `this` keyword. Once you have the right idea of it, it's useful - but I will not lose respect for you as a developer if, early in your JS coding you run into lots of "this.myFunction is not defined!" due to the manner a function is being called in. Don't worry, JS pros agree it's confusing and could have been designed better.

Answer (score 4):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

`this` in the global context just references the global `window` itself instead of the document.  The above link has a great example:

`console.log(this.document === document); // true`

`// In web browsers, the window object is also the global object:
console.log(this === window); // true`

`this.a = 37;
console.log(window.a); // 37`

I haven't tested this in all browsers, but it appears to be true in both Firefox and Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

So it really depends where this code is. Is it in the $(document).ready() or $(window).load()? If you are just inside:

```
$(function(){ });
```

Then that is just short hand for $(document).ready(). So you'll be referring to the document. Check it out: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Also $(this) means you are referring to the current object.

Comment: $(this) is nowhere, it's not in any of the expressions that you listed. It's just been written at the very beginning of the JavaScript file. As above answered, I think it refers to window.

Answer (score 0):

If this is the only line in your script, then the code is evaluated in the global execution context. Lets have a look what the specification says about it:

> [**10.4.1.1 Initial Global Execution Context**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.4.1.1)
>
> The following steps are performed to initialise a global execution context for ECMAScript code *C*:
>
> 1. Set the [VariableEnvironment](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.3) to [the Global Environment](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.2.3).
> 2. Set the [LexicalEnvironment](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.3) to [the Global Environment](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.2.3).
> 3. Set the [ThisBinding](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.3) to the global object.

The `ThisBinding` is the value that `this` resolves. So, in the global context, `this` refers to the global object, which is `window` in browsers.

For more (less formal) information about `this`, have a look at the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).